# How to get friends who have birthday today or in the next 7 days (week)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, social-network-friendship

before creating this topic I researched the entire community, but I did not find anything close to what I'm trying to do. I am developing a small social network which is a PHP project for academic purposes only.

---

I have the following tables in my database:

```
Table Name: users
Columns:
   id => INT (Primary Key - AutoIncrement)
   name => VARCHAR(200)
   birthdate => DATE
   login => VARCHAR(60)
   password => VARCHAR(60)

Table Name: friends
Columns:
   id => INT (Primary Key - AutoIncrement)
   idRequester => INT (Foreign Key - users>>id)
   requestDate => DATE
   idRequested => INT (Foreign Key - users>>id)
   confirmationDate => DATE
   situation => CHAR(1) (A=Accepted | P=Waiting | R=Rejected)
```

---

With the following query, I can get all the birthdays of the day (Without considering friendships).

```
SELECT id, name, DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%d/%m/%Y') AS dtbirth,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, NOW()) AS age
FROM users WHERE birthdate LIKE '%-06-21';
```

---

This is similar to a question raised in another topic here of the portuguese forum, in this link: [Here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39931/modelar-banco-de-dados-de-um-sistema-de-amigos)

I need to get all the friends who have birthday today or in the next 7 days given the current date, this from a particular user X. I don't know how to **JOIN** tables **users and friends** because we have two columns and if X is the requesting user, then I need to join with the requested one, otherwise X being requested, then I join with the requestor.

**That is, get all 'user ID 50' friends who have birthday today or in the next 7 days.**

---

If someone can help me, because I'm not sure how to perform a query that solve this problem and also gains in performance. I believe that it would help a lot of people, since the doubt is something frequent and for academic purposes. Thank you.

Comment: Ans what if you ask this question a few days before New Year's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi as per my understanding you require all the friends who're having their birthday's between today and next week for a particular user_id, and you also have confusion with how to pull all the friends since sometimes X person is the one who requested for friendship and sometimes X is the person who was requested for friendship.

I wrote below query, I hope it helps.

```
select ur.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, NOW()) AS age 
 from users ur 
 inner join
 (
    -- getting all the friends who are accepted and the user was requested
   (
      select f.idRequester as friends_id
      from users u
      inner join friends f
      on (u.id=f.idRequested)
      where u.id=103 and situation = 'A'
   )
   union
   (
     -- getting all the friends who are accepted and the user was requester

     select f.idRequested as friends_id
     from users u
     inner join friends f
     on (u.id=f.idRequester)
     where u.id=103 and situation = 'A'
    )
  ) temp
    on(ur.id=temp.friends_id)
    /*
       this part compares if the day of birth lies 
       between today or next 7 days. 
    */ 
     WHERE DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(curdate()), MONTH(birthdate), 
           DAY(birthdate))) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

NOTE: I have hardcoded the user_id, to make it dynamic you can probably use a stored procedure with parameters and replace the hardcoded part with it.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, it was exactly what I needed, I managed to understand now, using the union makes it possible to perform the join following the rules, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: There was a problem with clause in BETWEEN, I had not noticed what the other members said, and really, when you compare for example, today (24) with a 7 day break (it would already be the 1st of July). No results found. How to solve this problem?

Comment: try this where condition

 WHERE date(concat_ws('-',year(curdate()),MONTH(birthdate),DAY(birthdate))) BETWEEN 
          CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**: I assume that your `birthdate` column is holding `data` only not time and you have to use `OR` condition to satisfy one of two or both conditions true. It will return current date and `7th days` birth date records

```
SELECT id, name, DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%d/%m/%Y') AS dtbirth,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, NOW()) AS age
FROM users 
WHERE (birthdate = CURDATE() OR  birthdate = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))

--Replace `WHERE` with below line to Return records from Current date to next 7 days
WHERE birthdate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name, DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%d/%m/%Y') AS dtbirth,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, NOW()) AS age
FROM users 
WHERE birthdate between  CURDATE() and  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

Comment: That checks to see if they were born between now and a week from now?  Don't you need to avoid the YEAR part?

Comment: Thanks for the contribution.